# How do you differentiate between Server and Windows logins?

Tags: sql-server

SQL Server supports two kinds of logins:

- Server logins
- Windows logins

**How do you check whether a particular login is of one type or the other?**

I assume checking for a slash in the username is an unreliable way of doing this...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the column type_desc.

```
select *
from sys.server_principals
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188786.aspx

Comment: This is even better than my answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This seems to do the job...

```
SELECT name
FROM sys.sql_logins
WHERE name = ?
```

If you get back a row, the user is a server login or group; otherwise, it is a Windows login.

**UPDATE**: See [Sean's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32231790/14731) for a more reliable solution.

Comment: It may be a windows login but it could also be a windows group.

Comment: @SeanLange agreed. I've updated the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

catalogue view sys.syslogins has a column `isntname` if its value is set to one its a windows login if 0 its sql server login.

```
Select name 
     ,CASE 
           WHEN isntname = 1 THEN 'Windows Login'
           WHEN isntname = 0 THEN 'SQLServer Login'
     END  AS LoginType
 from sys.syslogins
```

### OR

```
SELECT Name 
       ,type_desc LoginType
FROM sys.server_principals
```

Comment: This view is only there for backwards compatibility. You should use the new system views instead. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178593.aspx